# How does t-SNE preserves embedding orders?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, tsne, dimensions

According to [the triplet loss Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_loss):

> t-SNE (t-distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding) preserves embedding orders via probability distributions, whereas triplet loss works directly on embedded distances.

From the Wikipedia page, I more or less understand how does T-SNE works with its two stages (first creating a probability distribution between pairs of objects of high dimensions, minimizing some divergence between some distributions), but I clearly don't understand how does t-SNE preserves embedding order from the description given by its Wikipedia page.

I am trying to understand this claim in order to translate the page into other languages. I don't have a very quick understanding of maths, don't be afraid to explain it as if I was a teenager.

Comment: What does it mean to "preserve embedding order"? I know the quote uses that language, but it seems a bit ambiguous to me. Could you say more specifically what t-SNE does that you'd like an explanation for?

Comment: I'm not sure, @user20160, but I assume that to preserve embedding order means to conserve which pairs of objects it has calculated the probability distribution of?